# Detecting and returning straight from given deck of cards

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

You have been given a deck of cards. The suit doesn't matter. There can be repetitions. The cards are represented by the numbers 1 through 13.

The goal is to find all possible straight in the given list. A straight is defined as 5 consecutive cards: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` is a straight and `10, 11, 12, 13, 1` & `5,6,7,8,9,10` are not. I wrote the code for this but my code doesn't work in all cases:

```
def is_straight(array):
    n = len(array)

    if n % 5 != 0:
        return False

    array.sort()
    prev = array[0]
    if n == 5:
        output = []
        i = 1
        while i < n:
            if array[i] - prev == 1:
                output.append(array[i - 1])
                prev = array[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                return False
        output.append(prev)
        return output

    else:
        l = int(n / 5)
        st_list = [[] for i in range(l)]
        set_track = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            if array[i] - prev == 1:
                for k in range(0, len(st_list)):
                    if prev not in st_list[k]:
                        st_list[k].append(array[i-1])
                        set_track = k
                        break
            elif array[i] - prev == 0:
                for k in range(0, len(st_list)):
                    if prev not in st_list[k]:
                        st_list[k].append(array[i-1])
                        set_track = k
                        break
            elif array[i] - prev > 1:
                del st_list[set_track]
                l -= 1
            prev = array[i]
        st_list[l-1].add(prev)
        return st_list


print(is_straight([1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9,10, 1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

Please let me know how to fix this code. It doesn't work for the above input.

Comment: Since the cards are bounded integers we can use radix sort in O(n). After using radix sort simply check for 5 consecutive cells. Should be a pretty straight forward linear time solution

Comment: It can contain multiple straights

Comment: The problem says find a straight not all straights. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Does 5,4,6,8,7 count as a straight?

Comment: @user2357112 judging by the fact he sorts the array and going by every other card game then yes

Comment: @user2357112 Yes it is counted as a straight.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your solution. I believe you are making the problem way more complicated than it needs to be. We can solve this problem in `O(N)` if we think the right way.

1) Since we have bounded inputs and we don't care about duplicate cards we can use a flag array. Set the position to True if we have the card and false if we do not

2) Since we need five consecutive cards we need only loop through the array once if we use modulus in a clever way and keep track of consecutive cards. Take it all together and we can get the following

```
def sol(myHand):
    hand = [False for _ in range(13)]
    for card in myHand:
        hand[card-1] = True 

    for i in range(len(hand)):
        staightCounter = 0
        while hand[i % 13] and staightCounter < 5:
            i += 1
            staightCounter += 1
        if staightCounter >= 5:
            print([ x % 13 + 1 for x in range(i-5,i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a full solution, but from what I see it looks like if your array is (10, 11, 12, 13, 1) representing (10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace), the `array.sort()` will move the 1 to the beginning of the list resulting in a `False` result. One way to correct this may be to set a condition if a 1 is detected in the input to test both the original array and a modified array replacing the 1 with a 14 then sorting the array before the test to account for the Ace being available for use at both ends of poker arrangements.

something like this

```
if 1 in array:
    ace_array = array.copy()
    ace_array.sort()
    ace_array.pop(0)
    ace_array.append(14)
```

then proceed to test both the `array` and `ace_array`